# Can you use less traditional Top-Level Domain Names, such as ".systems" or ".aero" in package names?

Tags: java, package

Let's say I own the domain name `alexander.website`, `akira.blue`, or anything else that uses a TLD that isn't 3 letters or traditionally used in packages. Can I name packages I create `website.alexander.packagename`, or is that frowned upon? Is it a technically sound idea?

Comment: You can use anything you want. There’s no requirement that it be a domain name at all. The reverse domain name convention was created to avoid conflicts: if you use a domain you have actually registered, and everyone else does the same, there won’t be any conflicts.

Comment: So, the short answer is that new TLDs can be used without violating that convention, and nothing will break because it was only ever a convention.

Comment: Why do you even think that would be a problem?